# Replace . to , in fetched currency amount of yahoo finance

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, yahoo-finance

I am using `excel 2010`.
I have the following vba function, which retrieves me currencies from yahoo finance. However, my problem is that I am using a German Version of Excel and the `.` is in this Version a `,`.

Therefore the converted currencies look like that:

[image]

That is the function I am using:

```
Function MYCURRENCYEXCHANGER(SourceCur As String, DestCur As String) As Variant
    Dim url As String
    ' http://quote.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=XXXYYY=X&f=l1  this is the link format where XXX is currency1 and YYY is currency2 '
    url = "http://quote.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=" & SourceCur & DestCur & "=X&f=l1"
    Dim myHTTP As New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
    myHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
    myHTTP.send ""
    If myHTTP.StatusText <> "OK" Then GoTo ServerErrorHandler
    If Not (WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(myHTTP.responseText)) Then MYCURRENCYEXCHANGER = 0
    MYCURRENCYEXCHANGER = CDbl(myHTTP.responseText)
    Exit Function

ServerErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Error. Could not convert currency"

End Function
```

Any recommendation how to convert the currency correctly so that the `.` is replaced by a `,` when fetched from yahoo finance?

I apprecaite your replies!

Comment: I guess that you have tried the dirty one : `MYCURRENCYEXCHANGER = CDbl(Replace(myHTTP.responseText,",","."))` because the CDbl should return you a numerical value that won't be considered as text in Excel whatever version you are using...

Comment: Since the `myHTTP.responseText` seems return string representation of numbers with `.` as decimal delimiter, I would simply use `Val` instead of `CDbl`. `MYCURRENCYEXCHANGER = Val(myHTTP.responseText)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function "Replace" to achieve this quite simply.

```
Function MYCURRENCYEXCHANGER(SourceCur As String, DestCur As String) As Variant
  Dim url As String
  ' http://quote.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=XXXYYY=X&f=l1  this is the link format where XXX is currency1 and YYY is currency2 '
  url = "http://quote.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=" & SourceCur & DestCur & "=X&f=l1"
  Dim myHTTP As New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest

  myHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
  myHTTP.send ""
  If myHTTP.StatusText <> "OK" Then GoTo ServerErrorHandler

  Replace(myHTTP.StatusText, ".", ",")

  If Not (WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(myHTTP.responseText)) Then MYCURRENCYEXCHANGER = 0
  MYCURRENCYEXCHANGER = CDbl(myHTTP.responseText)
  Exit Function

ServerErrorHandler:
  MsgBox "Error. Could not convert currency"

End Function
```

The Replace(string, searchtext, replacetext) function will change all occurrences of searchtext by replacetext in your string.

I've not tested it but I'm fairly confident that this should do the trick.